# how to read txt file and load it into a dictionay to filter the data

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

i have txt file data like:

```
network:4g,brands:Huawei,prices:20568,colors:silver,ratings:3
network:4g,brands:Vivo,prices:20490,colors:blue,ratings:3
network:4g,brands:Samsung,prices:37005,colors:gold,ratings:3
network:4g,brands:Samsung,prices:34744,colors:black,ratings:4
network:5g,brands:iPhone,prices:20921,colors:white,ratings:5
```

i was able to load "network:4g" as key but actually only "network" is the key
pls give me solution to load all data into a dictiomary and filter the data based on any field like
•   Show all mobiles whose price is less than 20,000

Answer (score 1):

With a regex you can easily extract the data:

```
import re

data = []
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        l = re.findall('([^:]+):([^,]+),?', line.strip())
        data.append(dict(l))
```

Output:

```
>>> data
[{'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Huawei', 'prices': '20568', 'colors': 'silver', 'ratings': '3'},
 {'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Vivo', 'prices': '20490', 'colors': 'blue', 'ratings': '3'},
 {'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Samsung', 'prices': '37005', 'colors': 'gold', 'ratings': '3'},
 {'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Samsung', 'prices': '34744', 'colors': 'black', 'ratings': '4'},
 {'network': '5g', 'brands': 'iPhone', 'prices': '20921', 'colors': 'white', 'ratings': '5'}]
```

Filter price < 25000:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: int(x['prices']) < 25000, data))
[{'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Huawei', 'prices': '20568', 'colors': 'silver', 'ratings': '3'},
 {'network': '4g', 'brands': 'Vivo', 'prices': '20490', 'colors': 'blue', 'ratings': '3'},
 {'network': '5g', 'brands': 'iPhone', 'prices': '20921', 'colors': 'white', 'ratings': '5'}]
```

You can also use `Pandas` to make data processing:

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype({'prices': float, 'ratings': int})
print(df)

# Output
  network   brands   prices  colors  ratings
0      4g   Huawei  20568.0  silver        3
1      4g     Vivo  20490.0    blue        3
2      4g  Samsung  37005.0    gold        3
3      4g  Samsung  34744.0   black        4
4      5g   iPhone  20921.0   white        5
```

Some examples:

```
>>> df[df['ratings'] > 3]
  network   brands   prices colors  ratings
3      4g  Samsung  34744.0  black        4
4      5g   iPhone  20921.0  white        5

>>> df[(df['prices'] > 20000) & (df['prices'] < 30000)]
  network  brands   prices  colors  ratings
0      4g  Huawei  20568.0  silver        3
1      4g    Vivo  20490.0    blue        3
4      5g  iPhone  20921.0   white        5

>>> df[df['brands'].isin(['Samsung', 'Huawei'])]
  network   brands   prices  colors  ratings
0      4g   Huawei  20568.0  silver        3
2      4g  Samsung  37005.0    gold        3
3      4g  Samsung  34744.0   black        4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to read and convert everything into a list of dictionaries so that you can filter out values:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    list_of_dicts = []
    for l in lines:
        vals_in_dict = {}
        for i in l.strip().split(","):
            vals_in_dict[i.split(':')[0]] = i.split(':')[1]
        list_of_dicts.append(vals_in_dict)

    print(list_of_dicts)
```

[image]

and then you can filter like below:

```
expectedResult = list(filter(lambda d: int(d['prices']) < 25000, list_of_dicts))
print(expectedResult)
```

[image]

Please note that I have only filtered out mobiles that are less than 25k